# Does Javscript's String.charAt method have O(1) time complexity?

Tags: javascript, string, time-complexity

In JS, are character lookups using String.prototype.charAt similar to looking up an array's index, or is there some extra work going on in the background?

Comment: This will probably vary by implementation, since the spec doesn't define any time complexity.

Comment: That said, [here is V8's implementation](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/4b9b23521e6fd42373ebbcb20ebe03bf445494f9/src/builtins/builtins-string-gen.cc#L553).  I don't know where `StringCharCodeAt` is defined.

Comment: Hi. Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68285926/8376759 (Sorry that I created the same question again and missed yours.)