# JavaScript charAt() runtime

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

What is the runtime complexity of the `charAt()` function in JavaScript with respect to the string length? Is it defined in EcmaScript (I failed to find it)? If not, what's the behavior in the common browsers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60007042/does-javscripts-string-charat-method-have-o1-time-complexity

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Comment: @Kordrad I can't find any information about the complexity on the MDN documentation page. Where do you see it?

Comment: You are not talking about number of iterations?

Comment: It does not relate to the number of iterations. I'm interested in the runtime complexity with respect to the string length. The question is whether `charAt` needs more time for a longer string than for a short string.

Comment: "*The question is whether charAt needs more time for a longer string than for a short string.*"  surely if it depends on anything, it'd depend on the argument you pass in. I do not see how `s.charAt(0)` would take more or less time if the `s` has length 100 or 10000.

Comment: Well, it would only depend on the argument if `charAt` is not O(1), wouldn't it? In other words, how much time would charAt need in worst case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small experiment: I generate texts of different lengths and perform `charAt` a million times.

```
function repeat(text, n) {
    const randomPositions = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randomPositions.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length));
    }
    const t0 = performance.now();
    for (let pos of randomPositions) {
        text.charAt(pos);
    }
    console.log("Elapsed time: " + (performance.now() - t0) + " ms")
}

const characters ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

// Thanks https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/generate-random-strings
function generateString(length) {
    let result = '';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

[10**2, 10**3, 10**4, 10**5, 10**6, 10**7].forEach(l => repeat(generateString(l), 10000000));
```

I run it in Chrome 91, Firefox 89 and Safari 14.

**Results:**

In Chrome and Firefox, the needed time does not seem to correlate very strongly with the text length indicating O(1). Some example times:

```
# Chrome:
Elapsed time: 37.40000003576279 ms
Elapsed time: 39.5 ms
Elapsed time: 38.30000001192093 ms
Elapsed time: 39.40000003576279 ms
Elapsed time: 46.39999997615814 ms
Elapsed time: 45.89999997615814 ms

# Firefox
Elapsed time: 255 ms
Elapsed time: 224 ms
Elapsed time: 269 ms
Elapsed time: 227 ms
Elapsed time: 424 ms
Elapsed time: 393 ms
```

In Safari, the needed time goes up:

```
Elapsed time: 94.00000000005821 ms
Elapsed time: 83.0000000000291 ms
Elapsed time: 93 ms
Elapsed time: 128 ms
Elapsed time: 294 ms
Elapsed time: 571 ms
```

**Did I miss an important factor? Please let me know!**